# Example showing tightness of Caratheodory's convex hull theorem

Tags: geometry

Let $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_k$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the convex hull of $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_k$. Let $P$ be a point inside $\mathcal{C}$. By definition, $P$ can be written as a convex combination of $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_k$. [Caratheodory's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_theorem_(convex_hull)) says that we need at most $n+1$ of the points.

What is an example showing that $n+1$ points might be needed? For $n=2$, we can consider a triangle on a plane, and it's clear that to write any interior point as a convex combination we need all three points. But for higher $n$ I'm having trouble visualizing the convex hull, and thus constructing the example.

Answer (score 1):

In dimension $n$, consider the $n$-dimensional [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), which is exactly the generalization of a triangle in the plane.

For instance, for $n=3$, take a tetrahedron.